# Add an additional configuration to the OOB EntWiki site definition?

Tags: configuration, site

I want to add an additional configuration to the out of the box Enterprise Wiki site definition.  Should I adjust the OOB site definition itself, or is there some way to staple it to the definition without touching the OOB files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change the OOB files for several reasons:

- Changing a deployed Site Defintion isn't supported
- Changing OOB files in general isn't supported and your changes may be overwritten by any SP/KB/Hotfix

If you want to make changes to what happens when a user creates an Enterprise wiki site, the you should make a feature which makes the changes needed and then use [Feature Stapling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861862%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to add that feature to Enterprise Wiki (ENTERWIKI#0).

If you want to create a completely new Configuration, then you need to develop your own site definition where you copy everything you want from the Enterprise wiki onet.xml. See [How to: Create a Custom Site Definition and Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454677.aspx)

Comment: Can I staple onet.xml additions to the ENTERWIKI#0 site definition?  Or am I stuck with programming the changes into an event receiver?  My preference is to staple a configuration section to the ENTERWIKI#0 site definition's onet.xml if something like that is possible.

Comment: In a feature you can do almost anything which you can do in onet.xml, but if it's a complete new configuration then see my additions to the answer